# Use of typedef on function

Tags: c++

In the following, how can i define my function with typedef syntax?

```
typedef void F();

//declare my function
F f;

//error
F f { }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of function would follow the usual syntax:

```
//declare my function
F f; //it is exactly equivalent to : void f();

//definition
void f() { cout << "hello world"; }
```

To test that the definition is indeed *the definition* of the functon which is previously *declared*, call the function `f()` just **after** declaration and **before** definition (read the comments in `main()`):

```
//declaration
F f;  

int main() 
{
    f(); //at compile-time, it compiles because of *declaration*
} 

//definition
void f() { std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; }
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/B4d95

---

As for why `F f{}` doesn't work, because it is specifically forbidden by the language specification. §8.3.5 (C++03) says

> A typedef of function type may be used to declare a function **but shall not be used to define a function (8.4)**.
>
> ```
> [Example:
> ```

```
   typedef void F();
   F fv; // OK: equivalent to void fv();
   F fv { } // ill-formed
   void fv() { } // OK: definition of fv

—end example]
```

Important points:

- A typedef of functon can be used to *declare* a function
- A typedef of functon cannot be used to *define* a function

Comment: What happens if i use F in function definition, why is the error?

Comment: @user974191: That is not how the language has specified it.

Comment: I see, so is it because the definition has to resolved at link-time and F will be unknown at the time, right?

Comment: @user974191: I didn't say that. I simply said, the language has not been designed like that, most likely because it is unnecessary, adding one more new syntax for function definition to the language, doesn't benefits anyone.

Comment: @user974191: Now see my answer. I quoted a reference from the language specification.

Comment: @user974191, the problem with using the typedef in the definition is that you can't specify the parameter names. Since the rule has to be consistent for functions that don't have parameters and those that have, you'd need a special syntax just to have a way to define parameter names in typedefed function definitions.